# Docker container hostname with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have multiple services running each a `mysql` database.
I'm using `docker-compose` to deploy my apps in docker.
**I need** that all these services are in the same network.
I use different docker-compose file for each service.

My issue is:
How can I prevent to container from being named the same (in docker dns) if they have the same name in different compose files.

Exemple:

**service1.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    network:
      - anetwork
[...]
```

**service2.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: "mysql"
    network:
      - anetwork
[...]
```

This two files are in separate folders. After launching all docker-compose up. The containers appears with `docker ps`. On named `service1_mysql_1` and the other `service2_mysql_1`.
But when I ping `mysql` dns name inside the network `anetwork`, both responds...

How should I fix this ? I am using bad practices ?

I have already tried:
- Changing the name in each compose files

Comment: How are you running the ping command? From inside a third container? If so, is it defined in service1.yml, service2.yml or elsewhere?

Comment: also, how is your network defined?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the options are either:

1. Change the name to be different in each compose file, which I understand you have already tried, e.g:

   ```
   version: '2'
   services:
     mysql1:
       image: "mysql"
   [...]
   ```
2. Use a fully-qualified name when connecting to each container, i.e. `service1_mysql_1` and `service2_mysql_1` in this case. Not ideal as it is generated but this name can be fixed by setting it explicitly using the `container_name` option:

   ```
   version: '2'
   services:
     mysql:
       image: "mysql"
       container_name: my-service1-mysql
   [...]
   ```

   Then a container that needs to connect to this database on the `anetwork` can connect using the hostname `my-service1-mysql`